# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - December 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 15th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for December 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              400
2   Monomeeth                 360
3   Allan                     310
4   Daniil Manokhin           190
5   grg, nohillside           150
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,798 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-12-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              182
2   nohillside                103
3   Daniil Manokhin           102
4   Glorfindel                 95
5   Allan                      86
```

A big thank you to all 17 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,443
2   Monomeeth                 564
3   Daniil Manokhin           435
4   Nimesh Neema              366
5   nohillside                287
```

A big thank you to all 74 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>**Note:** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      80
2   nohillside                 74
3   Nimesh Neema               56
4   Monomeeth                  40
5   IconDaemon                 23
```

A big thank you to all 17 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Daniil Manokhin           336
2   Nimesh Neema              275
3   Allan                     164
4   Monomeeth                 161
5   nohillside                 49
```

A big thank you to all 24 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Daniil Manokhin            79
2   Monomeeth                  70
3   Nimesh Neema               69
4   Allan                      63
5   Glorfindel                 36
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      76
2   Nimesh Neema               57
3   ⱮarkƬ                      42
4   Tetsujin, fsb              19
5   nohillside                 17
```

A big thank you to all 26 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      14
2   Nimesh Neema                9
3   grg, nohilside              8
4   bmike, Tetsujin             6
5   Glorfindel, Mark, fsb
    Ɱark Ƭ                      4
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Glorfindel                 79
2   Allan                      70
3   Nimesh Neema               60
4   grg                        59
5   nohillside                 49
```

A big thank you to all 44 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Copying blocks of text in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345611/copying-blocks-of-text-in-terminal)

   - Posted by: Mended
   - Votes: **28**
2. [How do I get old apps like Photoshop CS5 to work on macOS Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344670/how-do-i-get-old-apps-like-photoshop-cs5-to-work-on-macos-mojave?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C122.2161)

   - Posted by: user312788
   - Votes: **16**
3. [How can I remove 'Dark Mode' from Ms Office apps without disabling it across macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346579/how-can-i-remove-dark-mode-from-ms-office-apps-without-disabling-it-across-mac)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **11**
4. [Can I charge a 2017 MacBook Pro with a third-party USB C power adaptor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346048/can-i-charge-a-2017-macbook-pro-with-a-third-party-usb-c-power-adaptor)

   - Posted by: sam
   - Votes: **10**
5. [How can two people read the same book on different devices](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345919/how-can-two-people-read-the-same-book-on-different-devices)

   - Posted by: Martijn Vissers
   - Votes: **9**

   [Can I re-format OS X drive without removing it from my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345070/can-i-re-format-os-x-drive-without-removing-it-from-my-macbook-pro)

   - Posted by: sam
   - Votes: **9**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Copying blocks of text in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345611/copying-blocks-of-text-in-terminal/345613#345613)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **38**

   [What does the “arrow” icon shown in the iPhone status bar indicate?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344682/168832)

   - Posted by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **38**
2. [Can I re-format OS X drive without removing it from my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345072/168832)

   - Posted by: Mike Scott
   - Votes: **26**
3. [How do I get old apps like Photoshop CS5 to work on macOS Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344672/168832)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **18**
4. [How can I remove 'Dark Mode' from Ms Office apps without disabling it across macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346579/how-can-i-remove-dark-mode-from-ms-office-apps-without-disabling-it-across-mac/346580#346580)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **17**
5. [Can I charge a 2017 MacBook Pro with a third-party USB C power adaptor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346048/can-i-charge-a-2017-macbook-pro-with-a-third-party-usb-c-power-adaptor/346053#346053)

   - Posted by: Buscar웃
   - Votes: **16**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Safari on my Mac won't open because “Safari cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345712/safari-on-my-mac-wont-open-because-safari-cannot-be-opened-because-of-a-proble)

   - Posted by: LostSafari
   - Views: **12,677**
2. [How to solve blank Safari Window / Safari crash (10.1.2)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345678/how-to-solve-blank-safari-window-safari-crash-10-1-2)

   - Posted by: Khan Klatt
   - Views: **7,753**
3. [Can I charge a 2017 MacBook Pro with a third-party USB C power adaptor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346048/can-i-charge-a-2017-macbook-pro-with-a-third-party-usb-c-power-adaptor)

   - Posted by: sam
   - Views: **2,096**
4. [What does the “arrow” icon shown in the iPhone status bar indicate?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344679/what-does-the-arrow-icon-shown-in-the-iphone-status-bar-indicate?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C111.3933)

   - Posted by: user1561108
   - Views: **1,797**
5. [Can I re-format OS X drive without removing it from my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345070/can-i-re-format-os-x-drive-without-removing-it-from-my-macbook-pro)

   - Posted by: sam
   - Views: **1,336**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grg)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Daniil Manokhin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Daniil Manokhin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Glorfindel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/121968/glorfindel)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Mended](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/313759/mended)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth), [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [LostSafari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/314075/lostsafari)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In November our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **422 flags** with an average handling time of **35 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 428 comments
- deleted 237 posts
- closed 197 posts
- edited 363 posts
- created 137 posts
- created 496 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

Answer (score 2):

It’s great to see how everyone helps Ask Different. Thanks Monomeeth for posting this and letting everyone appreciate what work everyone does.

A HUGE thank you to the moderators and doing so much work for the site. Keep up the good work!

Comment: You have been pretty active and have contributed greatly to the site. Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: @NimeshNeema No worries!