# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - January 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 16th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for January 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     390
2   Daniil Manokhin           290
3   bmike                     200
4   nohillside                180
5   Nimesh Neema, Aristide    150
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.<sup>1</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,835 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-01-02).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Daniil Manokhin           156
2   bmike                     110
3   Nimesh Neema               90
4   Allan                      84
5   IconDaemon                 72
```

A big thank you to all 23 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,416
2   Monomeeth                 557
3   user97627                 511
4   bmike                     343
5   Daniil Manokhin           329
```

A big thank you to all 56 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>2</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 89
2   Allan                      74
3   Nimesh Neema               40
4   bmike                      33
5   fsb                        32
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Daniil Manokhin           421
2   Monomeeth                 231
3   Nimesh Neema              213
4   Allan                     122
5   fsb                        72
```

A big thank you to all 38 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     109
2   Nimesh Neema               95
3   Daniil Manokhin            69
4   Tetsujin                   43
5   Monomeeth                  29
```

A big thank you to all 25 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      85
2   Daniil Manokhin            39
3   Tetsujin                   27
4   fsb                        20
5   Ɱark Ƭ                     16
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      16
2   nohillside                 10
3   Tetsujin                    8
4   Ɱark Ƭ                      7
5   fsb                         6
```

A big thank you to all 11 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      88
2   Daniil Manokhin            43
3   nohillside                 30
4   grg                        23
5   bmike, Glorfindel          17
```

A big thank you to all 30 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Too many dots in Safari password fields](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349298/too-many-dots-in-safari-password-fields)

   - Posted by: Aristide
   - Votes: **15**
2. [Stuck with an old version of MacOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347938/stuck-with-an-old-version-of-macos)

   - Posted by: Catalin Catalin
   - Votes: **12**
3. [Do LAN transfers use both Ethernet and WiFi by default?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348725/do-lan-transfers-use-both-ethernet-and-wifi-by-default)

   - Posted by: Michael J. Caboose 2.0
   - Votes: **11**
4. [iOS always “resets” my apps after a while when they are minimized. How can I change that?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348837/ios-always-resets-my-apps-after-a-while-when-they-are-minimized-how-can-i-cha)

   - Posted by: Marcelo Assis
   - Votes: **10**
5. [How do I remove Outlook mail from Spotlight?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348537/how-do-i-remove-outlook-mail-from-spotlight)

   - Posted by: Fuzzy76
   - Votes: **9**

   [Can't run one particular program from Terminal without using its full path](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348035/cant-run-one-particular-program-from-terminal-without-using-its-full-path)

   - Posted by: Evgenii
   - Votes: **9**

   [Using macOS without an Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347673/using-macos-without-an-apple-id)

   - Posted by: Emil
   - Votes: **9**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Too many dots in Safari password fields](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/349300/168832)

   - Posted by: Aristide
   - Votes: **36**
2. [Stuck with an old version of MacOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/347940/168832)

   - Posted by: Steve Chambers
   - Votes: **25**
3. [Do LAN transfers use both Ethernet and WiFi by default?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348731/168832)

   - Posted by: Allan
   - Votes: **20**
4. [Can't run one particular program from Terminal without using its full path](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348037/168832)

   - Posted by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **19**
5. [iOS always “resets” my apps after a while when they are minimized. How can I change that?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348839/168832)

   - Posted by: nohillside
   - Votes: **18**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Too many dots in Safari password fields](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349298/too-many-dots-in-safari-password-fields)

   - Posted by: Aristide
   - Views: **2,706**
2. [Do LAN transfers use both Ethernet and WiFi by default?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348725/do-lan-transfers-use-both-ethernet-and-wifi-by-default)

   - Posted by: Michael J. Caboose 2.0
   - Views: **2,558**
3. [Stuck with an old version of MacOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347938/stuck-with-an-old-version-of-macos)

   - Posted by: Catalin Catalin
   - Views: **1,845**
4. [iOS always “resets” my apps after a while when they are minimized. How can I change that?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348837/ios-always-resets-my-apps-after-a-while-when-they-are-minimized-how-can-i-cha)

   - Posted by: Marcelo Assis
   - Views: **1,786**
5. [Is it not possible to make Apple Watch chime on the hour?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347805/is-it-not-possible-to-make-apple-watch-chime-on-the-hour)

   - Posted by: poige
   - Views: **1,667**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Daniil Manokhin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Daniil Manokhin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Aristide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/104453/aristide)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Aristide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/104453/aristide)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Aristide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/104453/aristide)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In January our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **500 flags** with an average handling time of **27 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 387 comments
- deleted 246 posts
- closed 221 posts
- edited 361 posts
- created 81 posts
- created 737 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Maximum possible score has been adjusted for 2019 to allow for changes to the Highest Voted Questions and Answers categories, and the Most Viewed Questions category.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting this out (some real-life distractions got in the way). I've also been working on the first annual edition (taking a while since it's the first one), so keep an eye out for that - I think people will like it! :)

Comment: How *DARE* you let life get in the way.. ;-P Thanx again for the great work, and I finally made the list... cool!

Answer (score 1):

Once again, thanks to *@Monomeeth* for posting this. It takes a lot of work to gather this data.

From the [last report:](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-december-2018)

- The moderators improved their flag handling time
- More flags were raised

A huge thank you to all!